# Listing min and max for all table columns based on schema

Tags: amazon-redshift

I would like to get min and max for all columns in specific schemas.

Is possible to resolve it using only SQL?

I know know to solve it by code but I would like to use only SQL.

edit:

I've solved it using Python but not sure if it's the best practice:

```
BASE_STATS = """
select
    '{schema}' as schema_name,
    '{table}' as table_name,
    '{column}' as column_name,
    count(distinct "{column}") as distinct_value,
    min("{column}"),
    max("{column}"),
    sum(case when "{column}" is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_values
from {schema}.{table};
"""

def execute(self, context):
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=self.conn_id)
    start_epoch = datetime.now().timestamp()
    columns_informations = pg_hook.get_records("select table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;")
    not_booleans_columns_informations = list(filter(lambda x: x[3] != 'boolean', columns_informations))
    base_stats_queries = list(map(lambda x: BASE_STATS.format(schema=x[0], table=x[1], column=x[2]), not_booleans_columns_informations))

    print(base_stats_queries)

    stats = []
    for query in base_stats_queries:
        result = pg_hook.get_records(query)
        result = result[0]

        end_epoch = datetime.now().timestamp()

        base_stats = (
            'master',
            'dwh_escale',
            result[0],
            result[1],
            result[2],
            start_epoch,
            end_epoch
        )

        stats.append(base_stats + ('distinct values', result[3]))
        stats.append(base_stats + ('min', result[4]))
        stats.append(base_stats + ('max', result[5]))
        stats.append(base_stats + ('num nulls', result[6]))

        print(stats)

    pg_hook.insert_rows(
        table='utils.column_stats', 
        rows=stats, 
        target_fields=['cluster', 'db', 'schema_name', 'table_name', 'col_name', 'start_epoch', 'end_epoch', 'stat_name', 'stat_val'])


    return None
```

Comment: Get the list of `table.column` for your schema from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Iterate over this rowset, build and execute queries retrieved the data.

Comment: Hey, interesting question. Is there a reason why you cannot use `plpgsql`? It is either not possible or very difficult to achieve it using pure `sql` :(

Comment: Because I'm using redshift and it only has a partial support to `plpgsql`. I've solved it using Python. Check edit on post.